# Is there anything like MVP[Diamond Badge] for Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I have seen users page it is ordered by Top reputated users...

- Is there anything like MVP for Stackoverflow?
- If so what is it?

**Suggestion:**

- A Diamond Badge for MVP would be my suggestion..

Comment: You sure like writing in *bullet points.

Comment: @random learnt from asking question in stack overflow.. All my - votes started to become + once i learnt to use bullets...

Comment: Meta doesn't work like SO

Comment: @Jaun Manuel Too true.  The interface looks the same, but that's just to confuse the new comers.

Comment: Damn, I just left an answer using bullets in meta.

Comment: Diamond is one of the hardest metals (if not THE hardest metal) known the man. Definitely harder than whatever they're making badges out of these days.

Comment: Diamond is a metal?  Funny, I just thought someone it was a crystalline lattice of carbon atoms.

Comment: what do you mean by "MVP"? Do you mean Microsoft MVP?

Comment: @C. Ross: in astronomy "metal" refers to any element other than hydrogen or helium. Perhaps Jean Luc Picard speaks like an astronomer? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal#Astronomy

Comment: @Jean Luc Picard: are you an astronomer?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: No actually I'm an archaeologist. And a starship captain. But mostly an archaeologist.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen We're not astronomers here, we're programmers.  Which means we use the definitions of the domain.  ... What domain is applicable here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On SO|SF|SU there are three ways of recognizing users (borrowing your bullets).

- Reputation, which is pointed out on the [users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users)

  - This is already an indicator of who is the Most Valuable Programmer
  - (we call him [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), though [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) is in pursuit)
- Badges, which reward special actions, like actually voting on things, and is seen on the aptly named [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges).
- Moderators, users who have pretty much full control on the site.

  - We elect those to help run the site.
  - These are the users who have the diamond after their name, Like [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) or [Diago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132480/diago).

What more do we need?

Comment: we need more bullet points.

Comment: I actually think some sort of flair for topic-badges might be worthwhile.  I'll have to ponder it...

Comment: I think some form of flair for bullet abuse might be worthwhile. :)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how would this work? What would such an MVP have to do and what does he or she have to offer SO that is not already there?

Between badges, reputation and chasing Jon Skeet, I think there is more then enough rewards on SO already. I am not entirely sure what an SO MVP badge or even an SO MVP will bring to the table?

Comment: @diago is there a diamond badge in pipeline... Will it ever come..

Answer (score 1):

It *wouldn't* be a diamond badge because the diamond (♦) is already used to denote the few *official* moderators appointed by the system.

But, since 10K is the highest level you can *earn* on the system, it might be a nice convention to have their flair indicate that plateau.

I'm not suggesting adding special abilities, MVP, a new badge, nor anything like that. Maybe just an unobtrusive indicator like a small text ("10K") placed after the username.

[image]

Comment: But I can tell you have 10K by glancing 15 pixels lower...

Comment: True. The `10K` is just a *"symbol"* ; a bit of accolade to recognize that a user has surpassed the milestone of full reputation abilities. I considered using another symbol not-like a diamond but I thought a little "10K" moniker was more recognizable. Just a suggestion.

Comment: People with 10k rep should have cornified flair.